# Interpretation of a 1x1 matrix, rank 1 vector, and a scalar?

Tags: list-manipulation

This is a seemingly trivial question, but I'd like to understand how to correctly treat matrices (and I guess rows/columns in Mathematica). I'm having fun figuring out how to express rows and columns specifically with their {} brackets in all the right places, and it's seemingly coming together; what I don't understand is the difference (in Mathematicas eyes) between a 1x1 matrix, a dimension-1 vector, and a scalar.

Setting

```
a=7
Dimensions[%]
```

returns `{}`. I take this as a 0-dimensional vector or a scalar as expected.

Now if I have a $1x1$ vector (from the result of two vectors $1x2 \cdot 2x1$)

```
Spa[1,2] = {{100}}
```

`Dimensions[%]` returns `{1,1}`, also as expected. In Mathematica's view, this is NOT a scalar, since it's a list. Subsequently, trying to multiply by a vector as a normal product will lead to an error, and we must use `Flatten` to obtain a result. We could "`Dot`" the $1x1$ matrix with another vector and get the desired result, but I don't understand why a dimension-1 vector from `Flatten[Spa[1,2]]` is treated the same as a scalar, yet we need to `Dot` the unflattened version? What's happening on the back-end?

EDIT: I am particularly interested in the difference between a dimension-1 vector and a scalar in mathematica.

Comment: "two vectors $1x2 \cdot 2x1$" sounds like two **matrices**, the result of the `Dot[]` product being a matrix. "Vectors" (of numbers) in *Mathematica* would have an `ArrayDepth[x]` of 1, not 2.  (It's 2 if the dimension are $1 \times 2$, indicated in *Mathematica* by `Dimensions[x]` being `{1, 2}` and having length 2.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you know why a scalar and dimension-1 vector are treated differently? I can simply extract with the Part function, but still am interested.

Comment: Not sure. In mathematics, they are treated as different objects, although there are natural [forgetful functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forgetful_functor) mapping 1x1 matrices to vectors to scalars. From a programming aspect, the *Mathematica* expressions for matrices, vectors, and scalars have different structures. You probably want the structures to behave in predictable ways.  For instance, you would not want a result that normally has the structure of a matrix to automatically become a scalar simply because the matrix result happened to be 1x1.

Comment: Makes sense; it's probably easy to forget that they are fundamentally different objects. It's not a big problem, but it does make sense that they shouldn't be treated the same. Thank you for your help! How can/should I close the question?